# Question about amplifier design

Tags: power, transistors, amplifier, bjt

I'm somewhat new to analog circuit design, and I have some questions about this circuit, which I came up with trying to understand how transistor amplifiers work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLYnFn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 is an emitter follower. When the input voltage is higher than the output, current flows through R1, which turns off Q2 through Q3 and Q4. But if the input is lower than the output, Q1 turns off, the voltage across R1 becomes zero, and the pullup R3 turns on Q2 just enough for Q1 to conduct again and regulate the voltage.

In the simulation it seems to work well, but the problem with it is that if a low-impedance load needs to be driven, R1 needs to be very small (around 1 or 0.47 ohms), and so that the constant current isn't huge, the threshold for it needs to be much less than a diode drop, and I can't figure out how to do that. Are there any good solutions? And if it can be fixed, are there any other serious flaws with it that I'm missing, or good reasons why I haven't come across anything that looks very similar to this?

EDIT:

This is the simulation output I get. The horizontal axis is V(in):

[image: Schematic and DC sweep simulation]

Q2 is meant to turn off completely just above the halfway voltage.

The nonlinearity and sudden drop in current at around 30V input is the voltage divider created by R1 and the load being hit, and the only way I can see to prevent it is to use a much smaller resistance, but a feedback network which can detect voltages smaller than a diode drop would be necessary, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of Q2, Q3 and Q4?

Comment: You sure that configuration works? In CircuitLab gain looks 1. Also, what is with the 5V source on the output? that is not like a conventional load?!

Comment: @Bruce Abbott: It's supposed to be a push-pull amplifier, and Q2 is to supply power to the load during the negative half of the cycle, where Q1 would just be off without it.

Comment: Make up your mind. is it an amplifier or a regulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a push-pull amplifier your circuit has two major errors.

1. The input to Q2 is referenced to a voltage 5V lower than the output. I suspect your intention was that V3 would create a 'virtual earth' at +5V, in which case the input should also have been referenced to +5V.

For simulation it may be easier to put the earthing point at V3's positive terminal, making the most negative part of the circuit -5V.

2. Q1 does a reasonable job of amplifying the positive half cycle, but during the negative half cycle the output is simply pulled down to ground (-5V). A push-pull circuit needs to amplify *both* half cycles.

Apart from not working properly, Your complicated method of splitting the positive and negative half cycles is unnecessary. All you need is one NPN and one PNP transistor, connected like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUNtKn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This simple circuit amplifies both positive and negative half cycles equally. However it has a small problem - each transistor needs about 0.6V of bias voltage before it begins to turn on. As a result the output will have a 'flat spot' when the input is less than 0.6V above or below ground. This is called [cross-over distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_distortion) - a major annoyance in audio applications because it produces harmonics which are very noticeable at lower volume levels.

To eliminate cross-over distortion you must provide each transistor with a bias voltage high enough to *just* start turning it on, but not high enough to cause excessive quiescent current flow. The bias voltage is usually generated using diodes or another transistor, thermally coupled to the output transistors so that their voltages track with temperature changes.

Here's an example:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIlzNM.png)</sup>

Resistors R2 and R3 provide enough bias current to develop ~0.6V across each diode, and also provide Base current to the transistors as the input voltage goes up and down (since the diodes block the signal).

Comment: As for (1), the input voltage was supposed to be centered on 5V, I guess that the schematic doesn't show it or I must have accidentally removed it. And (2), the output is not pulled to -5V on the negative cycle, it pulls until Q1 conducts, so that it can keep working as an emitter follower. I don't see how class-AB doesn't split the positive and negative cycles the same way.

Comment: If Q1 is always conducting then it is not push-pull (class B or AB). What you really have is just class A with an overly complicated active current sink.

Comment: I guess it makes the most sense to call it class A, and the idea of the complicated current sink is that its not extremely inefficient like a fixed current source, allowing the quiescent current to be much less than the maximum output current. Is that a valid solution, or is there a good reason why it can't work?

Comment: It works (when compensated to prevent oscillation and the input ground is referenced to +5V) but does not produce the saving you might be expecting. Q1 draws almost constant current. Q2 then has to sink the difference between that and the load current. Quiescent current is the same as class A, so no saving at idle. At peak positive output voltage the sink current drops to zero, but at peak negative voltage it rises to double the quiescent value. There is a small large signal power saving (~3%), but not nearly as much as class AB (30%).

Comment: I edited the question to show the intended operation. Q1 doesn't source constant current, it increases when the input goes above halfway. If the input is below halfway, Q1 draws only the (very small, relative to the load current) quiescent current, while Q2 tries to regulate it, sinking the large current from the load in the process.

Comment: I simulated your original circuit and it operated as I described. Now you simulate a version with different component values that appears to work in push-pull (Q1 on during positive half cycles, Q2 on during negative half cycles) but it isn't working well - above 30V Q1 is saturated and the input is powering the load through Q1's Base. Below 19V the signal goes through all 4 transistors, which is likely to cause instability due to the high loop gain and multiple phase shifts. You can keep tweaking the circuit trying to fix it, or admit defeat and just use a conventional push-pull circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you haven't seen anything similar is that it's mostly pointless — and a waste of power.

Ignoring the signal variations on V2 for a moment, the action of Q2, Q3 and Q4 is to maintain a constant voltage drop across — and therefore a constant current through — R1.

Now, when the signal voltage rises, there is a need for load current to flow, and this current is diverted from Q2 — its collector current is reduced. Similarly, when the signal voltage falls, additional current must be drawn from the load — Q2's collector current is increased.

So, instead of a normal emitter follower, in which Q1 provides current gain for the signal, you have this bizarre situation in which Q1's current is held constant, and the load current variations are driven by Q2 through your elaborate feedback mechanism.

In this design, the quiescent current (the current through R1 and Q1) must be higher than the peak current required in the load, and this current must flow at all times, regardless of the actual load current required at any given moment. This is not only much worse than a normal "class B" amplifier, it is also worse than a conventional "class A" amplifier.

I would also expect this circuit to be rather unstable. There is a lot of gain around the feedback loop, and at some frequency it will oscillate. Note that with no signal applied, you can consider Q1 to be a common-base amplifier with regard to any variations at the output node. At low frequencies, the feedback is negative, but at some high frequency, the phase shifts through the four transistors will add up to the point where it effectively becomes positive.

Comment: "In this design, the quiescent current (the current through R1 and Q1) must be higher than the peak current required in the load" -- The whole idea was that the quiescent current through R1 and Q1 is a small fraction of the peak load current, so that Q2 powers the load for the negative part of the cycle, and then turns off completely as the positive part rises.

Comment: That might have been the idea you had in mind at the time, but did your simulation confirm that this was actually happening?

Comment: I just ran the simulation in CircuitLab, and it confirms that the current in R1 varies hardly at all. I also increased the time resolution to 1 ns, and it confirms that the circuit oscillates very nicely with a period of about 1.4 us, with the current in Q2 spiking at over 600 mA!

Comment: reducing the resistance of the load, increasing the supply voltage, or reducing the feedback trigger voltage (which was the main point of my question) should show Q2 turning off and the current in R1 increasing.

Comment: That's up to you. I'm just saying that the approach is fundamentally flawed, so I'm not going to put any effort into trying to optimize it.